# Is $g(\lambda) = \mathbb{E}_{h}[f(h,\lambda)]$ continuous in $\lambda$ when $f(h,\lambda)$ is dicontinuous in $h$ and $\lambda$ at finite points.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

\begin{equation}
g(\lambda) = \mathbb{E}_{\bf{h}}[A(h,\lambda)], \bf{h}\geq0, \lambda\geq0.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
g(\lambda) = \int_{h=0}^{\infty}A(h,\lambda) f_{\bf{h}}(h) \,dh, 
\end{equation}
where $f_{\bf{h}}(h)$ is the probability density function of the RV $\bf{h}$.

I have the above function $g(\lambda)$, which is expectation of $A(h,\lambda)$ over $\bf{h}$. I am trying to understand the required conditions for it to be continuous in $\lambda$.

$A(h,\lambda)$ is discontinuous in both $h$ and $\lambda$ at some points.
I am able to show that for a given $h$ the function
$A(h,\lambda)$ is discontinuous at one value of $\lambda$. Similarly, for a given $\lambda$ the function $A(h,\lambda)$ is discontinuous at one value of $h$. Is this enough to show that $g(\lambda)$ is continuous in $\lambda$? What are the real analysis conditions required to prove the continuity of $g(\lambda)$?

3D -plot below shows one specfic case of $A(h,\lambda)$ as function of $h$ and $\lambda$.
[[image: One specfic case of <span class=]$A(h,\lambda)$ as a function of $h$ and $\lambda$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1o0X.png)

Comment: Do we know anything about the integrability properties of $f$? And what's your measure we're taking expectation with respect to? It looks like a case where you'd just like to apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: $h\geq0$ and $\lambda\geq0$. The expectation is over $h$.
Can i use DCT even when $f$ is discontinuous?

Comment: Yes, but what expectation are you taking? Is it $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b} f(h,\lambda)\textrm{d}\lambda$ for some appropriate $a<b$ or are we integrating with respect to some other measure?

Comment: And as for DCT, you need to check that for fixed $\lambda_0,$ we have $\lim_{\lambda\to\lambda_0} f(h,\lambda)=f(h,\lambda_0)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $h,$ where $\mu$ is the measure, you're taking expectation to. As soon as you have that and some integrable $g$ such that $|f(h,\lambda)|\leq |g(h)|$ no matter $\lambda$, you can apply DCT.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou 
Thank you for your reply and sorry for not mentioning the integration clearly. I updated the question with the integration. Please let me know the conditions required for this case.

Comment: Is $A$ bounded?

Comment: Yes, As shown in the example 3D plot it is between 0 and some $A_{max}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100004/discussion-between-sar1729-and-woolierthanthou).

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, if anyone stumbles upon this later:

It is crucial that $A$ is bounded by some constant, say $C>0$. Hence, note that for any $\lambda_0\geq 0,$ we have, for all but finitely many $h$, that $\lim_{\lambda\to \lambda_0} A(h,\lambda)=A(h,\lambda_0).$ Hence, we have the statement for a.e. $h$. Thus, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, dominating by the constant $C$ function (which is in $L^1(f_{\mathbf{h}}\textrm{d}h),$ since this is a probability measure), we have

$$
\lim_{\lambda\to\lambda_0} \int_0^{\infty} A(h,\lambda)f_{\mathbf{h}}(h)\textrm{d}h=\int_0^{\infty} \limsup_{\lambda\to \lambda_0}A(h,\lambda)f_{\mathbf{h}}(h)\textrm{d}h=\int_0^{\infty} A(h,\lambda_0)f_{\mathbf{h}}(h)\textrm{d}h,
$$

implying continuity.